# Function Pointer to member function of template class? (C++)

Tags: c++, function, pointers, member

I've been butting my head against this problem in an assignment I've been working on, and can't seem to get it to work at all. I wrote a little test class to demonstrate what I'm trying to do, and hopefully someone can explain what I need to do.

```
//Tester class
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Tester
{
    typedef void (Tester<T>::*FcnPtr)(T);

private:
    T data;
    void displayThrice(T);
    void doFcn( FcnPtr fcn );

public:
    Tester( T item = 3 );
    void function();
};

template <typename T>
inline Tester<T>::Tester( T item )
    : data(item)
{}

template <typename T>
inline void Tester<T>::doFcn( FcnPtr fcn )
{
    //fcn should be a pointer to displayThrice, which is then called with the class data
    fcn( this->data );
}

template <typename T>
inline void Tester<T>::function() 
{
    //call doFcn with a function pointer to displayThrice()
    this->doFcn( &Tester<T>::displayThrice );
}

template <typename T>
inline void Tester<T>::displayThrice(T item)
{
    cout << item << endl;
    cout << item << endl;
    cout << item << endl;
}
```

-and here's main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Tester.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Tester<int> test;
    test.function();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

-and lastly, my compiler errors (VS2010)

```
    c:\users\name\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\example\example\tester.h(28): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
1>          c:\users\name\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\example\example\tester.h(26) : while compiling class template member function 'void Tester<T>::doFcn(void (__thiscall Tester<T>::* )(T))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\name\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\example\example\tester.h(21) : while compiling class template member function 'Tester<T>::Tester(T)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\name\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\example\example\example.cpp(7) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Tester<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
```

Hopefully, my comments in the Tester class will tell you what I'm trying to do. Thank you for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: Make sure to add the homework tag if it is appropriate.  Also, take a look at `boost::bind`, specifically `boost::mem_fn`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not calling the member function pointer corrently; it requires the use of a special operator called the [pointer-to-member operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx).

```
template <typename T>
inline void Tester<T>::doFcn( FcnPtr fcn )
{
    (this->*fcn)( this->data );
    //   ^^^
}
```

Comment: Hi guys, trying this code render me with 2 strange errors, in OS X and NetBeans 

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Tester<int>::function()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "Tester<int>::Tester(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
, Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To call a member function via a pointer-to-member-function plus instance pointer, you need the `->*` syntax, minding operator precedence:

```
(this->*fcn)(data);
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. Trying to figure all that out was a nightmare full of ugly syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly add the object you message:

```
(*this.*fcn)(this->data); // << '*this' in this case
```

see also the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)